# Fractional part of integer multiples

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

If $x\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$, I can prove that 
$$x-\lfloor x\rfloor,\ 2x-\lfloor 2x\rfloor,\ \dots,\ nx - \lfloor nx\rfloor  $$
are all distinct. If we assume otherwise then
$$ (i-j)x = \lfloor ix\rfloor -\lfloor jx\rfloor$$
for $i\neq j$, and therefore $x\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Is this true if we consider $x\in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: What happens if $x=1/2$ and $n=3$?

Comment: @kimchilover Thank you!

Comment: @user8734617 True, I just corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=\frac{p}{q}$, then, for $k,n\in\mathbb Z$:

$$(k+nq)x-\lfloor (k+nq)x\rfloor=kx+np-\lfloor kx+np\rfloor=kx+np-\lfloor kx\rfloor - np = kx-\lfloor kx\rfloor$$

thus the values $kx-\lfloor kx\rfloor$ are *never* all distinct if $x$ is rational, and they repeat with the period at most $q$.